# Adodb.Connection not working in Excel VBA OS: windows 7 pro 64 bit

Tags: excel, windows-7, adodb, vba

I have an Excel file with VBA code, to import data from an Oracle database, which runs on Windows XP.

When I try on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit I get an error on the first line of below code.

```
Function getConnection2() As ADODB.Connection
  Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim strCnn As String

  strCnn = "Data Source=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXXX;"
  cnn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
  cnn.ConnectionString = strCnn

  cnn.Open
  Set getConnection2 = cnn
End Function
```

**Error**:  Compile Error: Automation Error

I searched MSDASQL for Windows 7 but was unable to find same on Microsoft website. They have it for Windows 2003
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=20065

Do we have any solution for this feels like its unable to create object for ADODB.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a complie error? 
I think in windows 7, the library you used on XP 32bit is no longer there

VBA Editor Tools-->Reference--> Add Microsoft ActiveX Data Object X.Y Library